# Make Chrome and Firefox remember password

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, google-chrome

I have a login form which redirects to a php script that then checks into the database if the user is registered and all that good stuff, what i want to do it's that i want firefox or chrome remember the username and password ass it happens on all other pages. 
Here is my code:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="../php/login.php" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="user">Username :</label></td>
                    <td><input name="user" id="user" type="text" /></td>                                        
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="password">Password :</label></td>
                    <td><input name="password" id="password" type="password" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td id="subCont"><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Login"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

And i'm going to be handling all the information with jQuery Ajax method

```
var form = $('#loginForm');             

            form.on('submit',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $this = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'post',
                    url  : 'php/login.php',
                    data : $this.serialize(),
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success  : function(r){

                    },
                    error : function(r){
                        window.alert(r.Message);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remembering usernames and passwords is an option in the user's browser, and not something that you can control.

Comment: yeah, but some sites offer that functionality, how can i do the same ?

Comment: @IsaacGonzalez Do you have an example? It's probably your browser doing it, not the website.

Comment: Well whenever i want to enter here to Stackoverflow, the browser remembers my username and password, also facebook remembers them

Comment: That's because those sites use cookies to remember your *login*, not your actual username and password.

Comment: So if i implement cookies in to the php script that handles this the browser should remember them ?

Comment: You should save some sort of *encrypted* cookie that uniquely represents the user in some way, which when read will log the correct user in. Make sure you put a checkbox to ask if the user if they're ok with saving your cookies, because some won't be.